# Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox - Mouse scroll down too quickly causes a page up

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in a virtual environment on VirtualBox v.4.3.28 in Windows 7. The problem is, when I scroll down too quickly with the mouse wheel a page up triggers. If I scroll slowly it's fine. Scrolling up on the mouse wheel does not have this problem no matter how fast I scroll up with the wheel.

I am seeing the problem mentioned [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5672).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this, by ejecting the guestaddition.iso and re-inserting it from the VBox menu.